# Reference instance attribute in parameterized decorator

Tags: python, caching, decorator, python-decorators

I have a method in a class that leverages `cachetools`'s `ttl_cache`. I want to be able to create different instance of the class with different `ttl` values.

The `ttl` value is specific as a parameter of `ttl_cache()`, but I am unable to reference instance attributes in the decorator's params.

```
class MyClass
    def __init__(self, ttl):
        self.ttl = ttl

    @cachetools.func.ttl_cache(ttl=self.ttl) # doesn't work. `self` is not available
    def expensive_operation(self):
        # do expensive operation
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure it out. It requires an inner function. The instance attribute is retrieved and made available in the scope of the outer function, then used in the ttl_cache decorating the inner function.

```
class MyClass
    def __init__(self, ttl):
        self.ttl = ttl

    def expensive_operation(self):
        ttl = self.ttl

        @cachetools.func.ttl_cache(ttl=ttl)
        def expensive_operation_cache()
            # do expensive operation
        
        expensive_operation_cache()
```